# Threshold - Transaction processing meaning?

Tags: transactions, operations

As per https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html

Low security consists of "Transaction processing" (Charging a fee or updating the sequence number for the source account). Which operations from [this list](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html) fall into the low security category?

Example: `Payment` operation will update the sequence of the source account. So does the payment operation fall under low threshold ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transaction processing is not refering to a group of operations and also is not a operation itself. It is kind of creating the transaction itself.

Let me explain it with an example:

- Account A (thresholds low=1, medium=2, high=2, two signers with weight=1 each)
- Account B (default)
- Account C (default)

Account A creates a payment transaction on behalf of B who sends some cash to C (the transaction is sourced from A, it contains one payment operation from B). Although A is a multisig account it needs only one signature because the act of crafting a transaction itself is low weight. Account A will be charged the XLM network fee and A will get its sequence number increased by one. (Obviously B will also need to sign the transaction cause it's his money)

The only low weight operations are `AllowTrust` and `BumpSequence` as stated in the docs.